# Possible to create ANY TYPE in SQL UDF?

Tags: types, google-bigquery

Is there any way to do something like the following in a templated sql udf in bigquery?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a_david_test.from(val STRING, type STRING) AS (
    (SELECT CAST(val AS type))
);
```

So that I could create a value of any output type? And be able to use it like:

```
select a_david_test.from("123", "INT64")
SELECT a_david_test.from('123', "FLOAT64");
SELECT a_david_test.from('2014-01-01', "DATE");
...etc.
```

Also, I think I'd need to parametrize the keyword `<TYPE>`.

---

After looking at the documentation a bit more, I believe what I'm asking for is if it is possible to use something like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` on a formatted sql string from within a UDF. Is that possible, or are there workarounds to that?

Comment: BigQuery needs to examine which data type an UDF returns before query execution. `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or `create table` statements are not allowed in an UDF, only in a procedure. You need to create an UDF for each case or return a string and parse it in your query.